# CMake executable location

Tags: cmake

I have a very simple directory structure:

```
Project
Project/src
Project/build
```

Source files are in `Project/src`, and I do the out-of-src build in `Project/build`. After running `cmake ../ ; make`, I can run the executable thusly: `Project/build$ src/Executable` - that is, the `Executable` is created in the `build/src` directory.

How do I set the location of the executable in the `CMakeLists.txt` file? I've attempted to follow some of the examples found at `cmake.org`, but the links that work don't seem to show this behaviour.

My `Project/src/CMakeLists.txt` file is listed here.

```
include_directories(${SBSProject_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
link_directories(${SBSProject_BINARY_DIR}/src)

set ( SBSProject_SOURCES
    main.cpp
    )

add_executable( TIOBlobs ${SBSProject_SOURCES})
```

And the top-level `Project/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (SBSProject)

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g3 -Wall -O0") 

add_subdirectory(src)
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You have a couple of choices.

To change the default location of executables, set `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` to the desired location.  For example, if you add

```
set (CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
```

to your `Project/CMakeLists.txt` **before** the `add_subdirectory` command, your executable will end up in `Project/build` for Unix builds or `build/<config type>` for Win32 builds. For further details, run:

```
cmake --help-property RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
```

Another option for a project of this size is to have just one CMakeLists.txt.  You could more or less replace `add_subdirectory(src)` with the contents of `Project/src/CMakeLists.txt` to achieve the same output paths.

However, there are a couple of further issues.

You probably want to avoid using `link_directories` generally. For an explanation, run

```
cmake --help-command link_directories
```

Even if you do use `link_directories`, it's unlikely that any libraries will be found in `${SBSProject_BINARY_DIR}/src`

Another issue is that the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` apply to Unix builds, so should probably be wrapped in an `if (UNIX) ... endif()` block.  Of course, if you're not planning on building on anything other than Unix, this is a non-issue.

Finally, I'd recommend requiring CMake 2.8 as a minimum unless you have to use 2.6 - CMake is an actively-developed project and the current version has many significant improvements over 2.6

So a single replacement for `Project/CMakeLists.txt` could look like:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (SBSProject)

if (UNIX)
  set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g3 -Wall -O0")
endif ()

include_directories (${SBSProject_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

set (SBSProject_SOURCES
    ${SBSProject_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp
    )

add_executable (TIOBlobs ${SBSProject_SOURCES})
```

Answer (score 10):

Another way of relocating the executable file location is via `set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH Dir_where_executable_program_is_located)`

Comment: New users should use "[```RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY```](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html)" since it supersedes "[```EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH```](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH.html)"

Answer (score 6):

> build/'config type' for Win32 builds.

For MSVC, to avoid the default "/Debug" created folder

```
set_target_properties(my_target
PROPERTIES 
RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```