# cmake choose output directory .exe

Tags: windows, cmake

I tried to define where to put the .exe generated by cmake + visual studio.
I put this in the cmakefiles.txt

```
IF(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL Windows)
INSTALL(TARGETS
    mialsrtkRefineHRMaskByIntersection              
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})

ENDIF(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL Windows)
```

but at the end all exe are in the folder of the vcxproj in a subfolder Debut.
is that normal ?
How can I specify the output directory ? 
on linux I put destination bin and it works.

Comment: You're setting the *installation* destination. Have you actually run the install step?

Comment: i have done the config and generation using cmake gui.
build using virtual studio
(the build is not performing the installation ?)

Comment: oh you're right. by default when I build the project it skips the installation.
I have to build it by asking for it specifically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake executable location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345792/cmake-executable-location)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're setting is the *installation* destination directory. In Visual Studio, installation is performed by building the special target `INSTALL`. That is equivalent to `make install` in Make world.

Note that you can also specify the *build* output directory. The ways to do that are :

- Variable [`CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html), which provides global settings.
- Target property [`RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html), which controls settings for a particular target.

Both of these have per-configuration variants, or sister variables/properties which affect other things than executables (e.g. `CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG`). Please see the CMake docs for details.