# The target name "lib/process.bin" is reserved or not valid for certain

Tags: c++, cmake

I have error when i run `cmake ..`  from build/ directory

> The target name "lib/process.bin" is reserved or not valid for certain

I tried to rename

1. lib/process.bin --> lib/proc.bin -- ERROR remains
2. **lib/process.bin --> process.bin -- OK**

Thus problem with  "lib"
How can I fix it?

Project directory

```
01_safe_process
├── build <--- run from here cmake ..
│
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── process.h
├── lib
└── src
    ├── main.cpp
    └── process.cpp
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

project(Process)

# specify the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

add_executable(lib/process.bin include/process.h src/process.cpp  src/main.cpp)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMake executable location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345792/cmake-executable-location). If you want to control the location of your generated executable, use `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` instead of prepending the directory path in the *target name*.

Comment: `Thus problem with "lib"` No, the problem is with `/`. `libprocess.bin` will be fine.